# Swift: Help me understand the Swift way of creating and using specialist classes derived from a base class

Tags: swift, oop

Coming from Ruby, I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around static typing.

I have a `Board` class that I wish to intialise with a `GameType`. I figured I would start with a base class:

```
class GameType {
    private(set) var targetNumber: Double = 10.0
    private(set) var divisions: Double = 10
}

class TenGame: GameType {
    override var targetNumber: Double { return 10.0 }
}

class HundredGame: GameType {
    override var targetNumber: Double { return 100.0 }
}
```

But, of course, the subclasses are of a different type. Meaning, this doesn't work:

```
let board = Board(withGameType: TenGame)
```

> "Cannot convert value of type 'TenGame.Type' to expected argument type
>   'GameType'."

So, after sulking, I remember protocols. This is close:

```
protocol GameType {
    var targetNumber: Double { get }
    var divisions: Double { get }
}

extension GameType{
    var divisions: Double { return 10.0 }
    var targetNumber: Double { return 10.0 }
}

class TenGame: GameType {}
```

But I still have to coerce my game type:

```
let board = Board(withGameType: TenGame() as! GameType)
```

Which can't be good!

I have a feeling that I'm missing a few key concepts here. Is this pattern at all possible in Swift? How do I do it in the Swift way?

Comment: Where's declaration of `Board` class?

Comment: Also error says that you're trying to pass `type` when `instance` of the `type` is expected.

Comment: Doh, I should have paid more attention to what the error actually said rather than what I believed it said. Yes, my problem is that I'm not sending the instance. `let board = Board(withGameType: TenGame())` works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I wasn't paying attention to the error message:

> "Cannot convert value of type 'TenGame.Type' to expected argument type
>   'GameType'."

Here, I'm only passing the class type:

```
let board = Board(withGameType: TenGame)
```

My `Board` class requires an instance and so I should be initialising it with:

```
let board = Board(withGameType: TenGame())
```